# Go time.Time String() adds "+0000 +0000", why?

Tags: go

I'm retrieving time from a Postgres DB.

Let's say it is:

`2020-02-27 08:57:36.774147+00`

Now I wanna write it in output like a string and I do it like this:

```golang
var myTime time.Time

fmt.Println(myTime.String())
```

In output it writes something different:

`2020-02-27 08:57:36.774147 +0000 +0000`

I need that value to be the same because I need to query something else with it.

---

Maybe the same issue is described here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11712

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you need is `time.Format`. Replace "myTime.String()" with "myTime.Format(layout)" with a desired layout as the argument (e.g. the predefined "time.RFC3339" or a reference time format "2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000-07").

go doc:

```
func (t Time) Format(layout string) string
    Format returns a textual representation of the time value formatted
    according to layout, which defines the format by showing how the reference
    time, defined to be

        Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006

    would be displayed if it were the value; it serves as an example of the
    desired output. The same display rules will then be applied to the time
    value.

    A fractional second is represented by adding a period and zeros to the end
    of the seconds section of layout string, as in "15:04:05.000" to format a
    time stamp with millisecond precision.

    Predefined layouts ANSIC, UnixDate, RFC3339 and others describe standard and
    convenient representations of the reference time. For more information about
    the formats and the definition of the reference time, see the documentation
    for ANSIC and the other constants defined by this package.
```

Comment: Ok I can query now but the time is not the same. Isn't?

Comment: The time is the same, but simply represented as a string per the format or the layout string you supply to the `Fomat()` function.

Comment: If I use `time.RFC3339` I cannot query in DB. If I use `time.RFC3339Nano` yes.

Comment: I mean DB found nothing with former one.